# Alteração do data type de uma coluna sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Bom dia.

Tenho a coluna `CliTelCel char(10)` na tabela de `Clientes`, preciso alterar `char(10)` para `char(11)`. Porém essa coluna já existe dados, qual seria a melhor forma de proceder neste caso, sem perder os dados já existentes e fazer a devida alteração?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual banco de dados você está usando?

Comment: char ou varchar?

Comment: @WendelRodrigues estou usando Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo para char(11)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Antes de tudo, tenha um Backup, isto é a garantia de que nada sera perdido.

Para alterar o tipo ou tamanho:

```
ALTER TABLE Clientes ALTER COLUMN CliTelCel char(11)
```

Os dados não serão perdidos pois você apenas aumentou o tamanho da coluna.

Se preferir também pode inserir algum dado para completar a coluna (ex: 0)

```
Update  Clientes set CliTelCel= '0'+CliTelCel
```

Answer (score 3):

```
alter table Clientes alter column CliTelCel char(11)
```

Answer (score 2):

Considerando que o `SGBD` seja `SQL Server` você pode alterar o tipo diretamente:

```
ALTER TABLE [tabela] ALTER COLUMN [coluna] char(11);
```

Comment: Mas e os dados que já existem la? Não será afetados?

Comment: Não, os dados continuam lá. O único problema seria se você deletasse a coluna